# Traversal checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web

I want to make checkbox such that if parent checkbox is checked then all the children checkbox is clicked. and if **any** of the children checkbox is clicked then parent checkbox is clicked. 
I have written code but it is not working properly. When I uncheck child checkbox then parent checkbox got unchecked despite having other child checkbox being clicked.

```js
$("#firstParent").on('change', function() {
  $('.child-1').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".child-1").on('change', function() {
  $('#firstParent').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="firstParent"><input type="checkbox" id="firstParent"/>Property</label>
<ul class="first-parent-child">
  <li>
    <lable>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child-1" id="f-1" /> Edit Property
    </lable>
  </li>
  <li>
    <lable>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child-1" id="f-2" /> Add Property
    </lable>
  </li>
  <li>
    <lable>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child-1" id="f-3" /> Remove Property
    </lable>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add some  code here

Comment: Ofcourse. have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that there's no `lable` element; it's `<label>`.

To achieve what you require, you can use DOM traversal to find the related child checkboxes to the one which was changed. The advantage of this pattern is that it will work for any number of nested checkbox levels. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  // child
  $(this).closest('label').next('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  
  // parent
  $(this).closest('ul').prev('label').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" /> Property
</label>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" /> 
      Edit Property
    </label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" /> 
          Sub property #1
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" /> 
          Sub property #2
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" /> 
      Add Property
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" /> 
      Remove Property
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah. But I want to add one more property that 'if any child checkbox is selected then parent checkbox got selected automatically'.

Comment: I updated the logic for you. Note that the checking of parent checkboxes may complicate the logic when there are multiple child siblings. I'd  suggest starting a new question if you run in to some issues

Comment: It's not working. When I un-select one child checkbox, then parent checkbox got un-selected, despite having other child checkboxes selected.